# Oozie workflow fails saying Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig, oozie

I have defined an oozie worflow with 2 PIG actions.

The 1st action works fine. 
The 2nd PIG action fails with the error:

*ERROR 0: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING*

**Stacktrace:**

```
org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.getStats(MapReduceLauncher.java:822)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.launchPig(MapReduceLauncher.java:452)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.launchPig(HExecutionEngine.java:280)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.launchPlan(PigServer.java:1390)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1375)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.execute(PigServer.java:1364)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:415)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:398)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:171)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:234)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:205)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:81)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:495)
    at org.apache.pig.PigRunner.run(PigRunner.java:49)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain.runPigJob(PigMain.java:288)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain.run(PigMain.java:228)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:39)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain.main(PigMain.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:450)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.ensureState(Job.java:294)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.getTaskReports(Job.java:540)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.shims.HadoopShims.getTaskReports(HadoopShims.java:235)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.getStats(MapReduceLauncher.java:801)
```

Comment: Can you post the workflow in question?

Comment: Was able to get rid of the error though i don't know what exactly/specifically caused the issue.
I mainly doubted on the data dependency between the two actions.

But this is what I observed:
In the 1st action's <prepare> tag, I was cleaning up few files.
In the 2nd action's <prepare> tag, few files which were cleaned up previously, were being cleared again.

Once I removed that, I did not face this error anymore. 
If you have any more insight, why this exactly happened, please do share.